# Possible to move/resize windows from external processes [C++/Windows]

Tags: c++, windows, process

Is it possible to move or resize windows from external processes with the Windows API?

For example, how would you write a program that lists out all the currently opened windows, let the user select two of them, then have the program place them side by side on the screen?

Comment: Start with `EnumWindows` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx  Then write some code.  If you still have questions post what you have when asking.

Comment: If you don't necessarily need to code it from scratch using Windows API, lot of stuff, including windows manipulation can be scripted using AutoHotkey.

Comment: Access to User objects is secured by the associated Desktop and  WindowStation. Typically a Process [connects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684859) to the "WinSta0" interactive WindowStation, and a Thread [connects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686744) to the "Default" Desktop. These objects grant all access to the logon-session SID of the Session user, but there can also be [Job object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684152) restrictions and Process integrity-level [UIPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd388202) restrictions.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. I'm now capable of answering my own question. ^^

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Richard Critten for a point in the right direction.

In order to obtain a list of all windows, one may use EnumWindows along with SetWindowPos to modify each windows' position and resolution.

This example moves every visible window 50 pixels to the right:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam) {
    if(IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) {
        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
        SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, rect.left + 50, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

int main() {    
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running that as a standard user (medium integrity) with at least one elevated window (high integrity) on the Desktop. UIPI policy blocks your access to the high-integrity windows.